# Searching for data from mysql, using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem in making a searching function in php. I am trying to change the column to be searched by, using and html drop down box. It is also supposed to use placeholders (%?%), so that I can do a global search. When I search for anything with the letter 'b', it simply displays all the records (all of them, when it is only supposed to display the ones with the letter 'b' in it).

The code is given below:

HTML (Please not this is an edited version, and the problem seems to be in the PHP file):

```
    <html lang="en" class=" js csstransforms3d csstransitions">
        <head>
    <script>
    function showUser() {

    var querycolumn = document.getElementById('querycolumn').value;

    var query = document.getElementById('query').value;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","contactsearching.php?querycolumn="+querycolumn+"&query="+query,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function userdata(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("userdetail").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("userdetail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","searchingforcontact.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
<section class="flexform" style="display:inline-block;">

<div id="txtHint" style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;"><b>The Contacts Which Are In The Contact Group Chosen Shall Be Displayed Here:</b></div>
                    <form>
                    <label style="clear:both;"><strong>Searching Parameter:</strong></label>
                    <select name="querycolumn" id="querycolumn" style="float:left;">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Choose A Parameter To Search By</option>
                    <option value="CustomerID">Customer ID</option>
                    <option value="CustomerBusinessName">Business Name</option>
                    <option value="ContactPerson">Contact Person</option>
                    <option value="Department">Department</option>
                    <option value="OccupationalTitle">Occupational Title</option>
                    <option value="EmailAddress">Email Address</option>
                    <option value="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</option>
                    <option value="EXT">EXT</option>
                    <option value="FaxNumber">Fax Number</option>
                    <option value="BusinessAddress">Business Address</option>
                    <option value="BusinessCity">Business City</option>
                    <option value="BusinessState">Business State</option>
                    <option value="BusinessZipCode">Business Zip Code</option>
                    <option value="BusinessCountry">Business Country</option>
                    <option value="PostalAddress">Postal Address</option>
                    <option value="PostalCity">Postal City</option>
<option value="Comment">Comment</option>
</select>
<br></br>
                    <label style="clear:both;"><strong>Value Searching For:</strong></label><input type="text" name="query" style="float:left;" id="query" />
                    <input type="button" onclick='showUser()' value="Initiate Searching Sequence" style="float:left;"/>
<br></br>
                    </form>

                </section>
</body></html>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
$querycolumn = $_GET['querycolumn'];
$query = $_GET['query'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","my_db");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

echo "<table border='4'>
<tr>
<th>Customer ID</th>
<th>Customer Business Name</th>
<th>Contact Person</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>";

$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT CustomerID, CustomerBusinessName, ContactPerson, Department, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, Comment FROM  `Contacts` WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $querycolumn, $query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5, $col6, $col7);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("<tr> \n <td><a href onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col1</a></td> \n <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col2</a></td> \n <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col3</a></td> \n <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col4</a></td> \n <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col5</a></td> \n <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col6</a></td> <td><a href='#' onclick='userdata($col1)'>$col7</a></td> \n \n </tr>", $col1, $col1, $col1, $col2, $col1, $col3, $col1, $col4, $col1, $col5, $col1, $col6, $col1, $col7);
    }

?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you can't do this `WHERE ?` - Assign a variable or select an actual column name. It doesn't know how to "look ahead".

Comment: try using  `WHERE $querycolumn LIKE` instead of `WHERE ? LIKE`

Comment: Thanks SOO MUCH!!!
It's working. Put this down as an answer, and I'll select it as the Best! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Thanks SOO MUCH!!! It's working. Put this down as an answer, and I'll select it as the Best! :D"*

**As requested:**

You can't do this `WHERE ?`

Assign a variable for your column or select an actual column name.

MySQL doesn't know how to "look ahead".

I.e.:

```
$column = "column_name";
WHERE $column LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')")
```

or

```
WHERE column_name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')")
```